# "mousePressed/mouseClicked" is not working for any reason

Tags: java, mouseevent

So basically , I'm doing an arkanoid , and I want that when I click in my programm, an action starts.

This is my code so far:

```
canvas.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mousePressed(e);
            player.mousePressed(e);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseMoved(e);
            player.mover(e.getX());
        }   
        
        
        
    });
```

The mouseMoved is working.

Player.mousePressed =

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    this.setSpace(true);
    switch (e.getButton()) {
        case MouseEvent.BUTTON1 : space = true; break;
    }
    //This is only for test 
    System.out.println(e.getButton());
    if (this.isSpace() == true) {
        //This is only for test 
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

If this should works, it should send me two syso but it doesnt send it. I also tried it with MouseClicked but it also doesnt work.

Comment: Have you attached the MouseAdapter to anything (i.e. Component.addMouseListener(...)

Comment: @ControlAltDel If its works, it should send the information to player.mousePressed, didnt tho?

Comment: "it should send..." not if you haven't attached it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
canvas.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
```

`Component.addMouseMotionListener` is declared as:

```
public void addMouseMotionListener​(MouseMotionListener l)
```

`MouseMotionListener` extends `EventListener` and adds the methods `mouseDragged` and `mouseMoved` but not `mousePressed`.

So you want to `addMouseListener` as well as `addMouseMotionListener​`. `MouseAdapter` implementing two distinct interfaces has done you in.